# How do I prevent the Blazor WebAssembly application from reloading when I open a page in a new tab?

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, webassembly

When I first open the site, it shows a loading screen. When I navigate around the pages, the loading screen doesn't show unless I open the page in a new tab.

I assume this happens because since it's a new tab, it's treated as a new session so it goes through the loading screen again. Is there a way to "transfer" the session when the user opens a new tab?

I tried this with different browsers and the same thing happens.

Comment: No.  Each browser session is a new SPA.

Comment: You can't prevent it but you could consolidate the tab data into shared `localStorage` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=webassembly